# extract_patches_2d max_patches param behaviours

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm using `sklearn` version `0.18.2`

In particular, I'm using [this function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html) for extracting image regions.

This function has one funny argument, namely `max_patches` which says how many patches function should extract from the image.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py), lines `228-238`, if the number of requested samples is higher than the number of patches available in the image, an exception is raised.

In my image set I have images of different sizes: from really tiny images to full HD ones. And now this is a problem as when I try to request, say, 1e6 patches, it throws an error on small images.

I have two questions: 
First one is constructive: how do I workaround this? I think this very normal desire: I want no more than a million patches from each image. Due to memory constraints I would not like to extract all images and then trim result array to a desired size.

Second: what was the reasoning behind introducing such a behaviour? Why not do something like `return min(max_patches, all_patches)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the workaround I've found is a bit ugly. However, one can use a private function from this module, namely

`<sklearn feature extraction import>.image._compute_n_patches`, which takes 4 arguments: image height, image width, window height, window width.

So I call it:

return `skfe.image._compute_n_patches(image_and_pattern.shape[0],image_and_pattern.shape[1],geometry[0], geometry[1])`

Now, there is another problem: if you pass this max_patches argument exactly equal to the number of available patches, it will still fail you, because of this line in the code:

```
if (isinstance(max_patches, (numbers.Integral))
        and max_patches < all_patches):
```

This `<` conditions does not allow one to get exactly maximum number of available patches.

Therefore, after you've obtained the number of patches you can request, you could do something like this:

```
    if self.max_patches_per_image > self.compute_n_patches_wrapper(image_and_pattern, feature_extraction_config.geometry):
        max_patches_allowed = None
    else:
        max_patches_allowed = self.max_patches_per_image
```

Then you can just pass `max_patches=max_patches_allowed`. If `None` is passed, then function will correctly return the maximum amount of patches available.